# Limit of Infinite series, Continuity proof, Multi variable Calculus

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

as part of a continuity proof, I had to evaluate $$lim_{k \to \infty} \left | (1+\frac{1}{k})^2\cdot \sin (y) \right |$$

the step to

$$lim_{k \to \infty} \left | \frac{{}(k+1)^2\cdot \sin (y)}{k^2} \right |$$

I follow fine, but then $(k+1)^2$ is replaced with $k^2$. This I don't follow. Why can the 1 just be dropped?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a shortcut for the fact that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}{(k+1)^2\over k^2}=1$$

You can see it without reducing

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(1+{1\over k})=1$$

Because $1/k\to 0$...

Comment: Of course. Thanks! Seems i had a blackout

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 0):

In limit of infinite series, the most important thing is the variable with greater power. Because the result of infinity divided by infinity uncertanities is the rate of coefficients of the variable with greatest power. For example if your equation is (k^3 + k^2 + k + 1 ), you can reduce all the values except k^3.